# Importing matplotlib results in 'DLL load failed while importing _cext' error, how can I resolve it?

Tags: dll, load

> > > import matplotlib
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 246, in 
> > > *check_versions()
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init**.py", line 240, in *check_versions
> > > module = importlib.import_module(modname)
> > > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> > > return _bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> > > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver_*init**.py", line 8, in 
> > > from ._cext import (
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.

i have reinstalled the libraries
reinstalled the python
downloaded msvcp71.dll and msvcr72.dll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed while importing \_cext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824703/matplotlib-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-cext)

Comment: have you tried installing msvc-runtime?