# Having an error with executing my code specifically matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im not sure whats going on but  i have a few errors in my python code here they are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacym\Plc_Math\pythonProject3\PLC_PUMP_GALLONS.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure

  File "C:\Users\pacym\Plc_Math\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
    _check_versions()

  File "C:\Users\pacym\Plc_Math\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pacym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pacym\Plc_Math\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824703/matplotlib-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-cext.